# Error con las url al listar productos desde archivo index.html

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Estoy tratando de listar productos en un archivo ***index.html***, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Tengo este archivo de las url de la aplicación:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello'),
 url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail)
]
```

Estoy tratando de acceder a este método que se encuentra en el archivo ***views.py***:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Product


def product_detail(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    template = loader.get_template('product_detail.html')
    context = {
    'product': product
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

y este es el archivo ***index.html*** donde listo los productos y me muestra error en el navegador al momento de ejecutar la aplicación:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     {% load staticfiles %}
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
          scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pr in product %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'products.views.product_detail' 
                    pk=pr.pk %}">
                    {{pr.name}}    
                </a>
                {{pr.description}}
                <img src="{{pr.image.url}}" alt="">               
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for pr in product %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'products.views.product_detail' pk=pr.pk %}">
            {{pr.name}}    
        </a>
        {{pr.description}}
        <img src="{{pr.image.url}}" alt="">               
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comencemos con el for, este no es el principal problema pero no puedes iterar un solo objeto, cuando haces el get_object_or_404 estas pidiendo por un solo objeto y no por varios para realizar el for, lo que puedes hacer es un if, para ver si recibimos el producto. Usa `product.name`, `product.description`, ...

Ahora si el error esta en `<a href="{% url 'products.views.product_detail' pk=pr.pk %}">` deberia ser <`a href="{% url 'products' pk=pr.pk %}">` . La razon?, cuando usamos el parametron `{% url '' %}` , estamos pidiendo por el nombre que le asignamos en el archivo **urls.p**y y no a la function.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

#app_name='tu_nombre' #Si esto es una app agregale nombre para que la diferencie de las otras app y agregalo en la url de esta manera 'tu_nombre:products'

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello'),
 url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='products')
]
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciona a la perfección.!!